# difference between st_equals and equal sign

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have strange thing happening in postgresql DB. I would like to understand what is the major difference between using st_equals and using the equals (=) sign ex :

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE st_equals(the_geom, st_astext('POINT(962952.534 6469066.353)'));
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE the_geom=st_astext('POINT(962952.534 6469066.353)');
```

An this code will not be the same as

```
SELECT * FROM x where st_geohash(st_transform(the_geom, 4326))=st_geohash(st_astext('POINT(962952.534 6469066.353)'));
```

and not even the same as

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE st_astext(the_geom)=st_astext('POINT(962952.534 6469066.353)');
```

I would like to understand why the result of these request differ

EDIT: so this question was mark as duplicate, I didn't found this post about `st_equals` and equal sign at the time. About converting to text with `st_astext` I was thinking about losing precision may cause the difference. But about `st_geohash` ?

Comment: ST_Equals — Returns true if the given geometries represent the same geometry. Directionality is ignored. While equal is a Comparison Operator.

Comment: My guess would be that comparing geometrics “could” have different result than comparing if two statements are equal (with the equal comparison Operator). Can’t go further since I don’t have experience with your direct issue

Comment: Comparing geometries after casting them to text is for sure inaccurate because of inaccuracy of floating point conversions. Another thing is that "=" and "ST_Equals" just are not the same. You will find many old questions dealing with this, including https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223342/what-does-it-mean-when-st-equals-returns-false-and-returns-true.