# Find all geometries in one table that do not exist in another

Tags: postgis, polygon, postgresql, performance, comparison

Using PostgreSQL and PostGIS, I have two tables of polygons, and I need to know which of the records in table p1 do not exist in table p2.  I do not have additional information available (e.g. ids) - I need to make the determination based solely on the geometry.

A typical database solution is to use a left join

```
SELECT p1.geom from schema1.parcel p1
   JOIN schema2.parcel p2
    ON st_equals(p2.geom, p1.geom)
  WHERE
    p2.pid is null
```

This works fine for very small numbers of rows, but as the number of rows increases, it becomes very slow.  Both geometry fields are indexed using gist.  I have ~200K rows in a test set, and I let it run for a few hours and it didn't complete.

I noticed that using `on p2.geom = p1.geom` instead of `st_equals` performs much faster (a matter of seconds).  I *might* be able to get away with using `=`, but the two are not equivalent and I would prefer to use `st_equals`.

**Is there a generally-accepted best approach for this?**  Surely, it's a fairly common problem?

I'm wondering if there is a superior approach for writing such a query with `st_equals`?  Alternatively, it has crossed my mind to do something along the lines of hashing each geometry, storing the hashes, and comparing those instead.  Not sure if the expense of doing so is worth it...

Edit: it's probably pertinent to mention that both tables will (likely) have 5-10 million records, and I would expect a relatively small number of differences.  Maybe 5-10%, but that's just a guess - I anticipate many matching geometries and few non-matching.

Note: I posted a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77513324/why-does-postgres-optimizer-switch-to-nested-loop-for-join) on stackexchange that was more about the Postgres optimizer.  To me, they are different enough to warrant a new question...

Comment: I'm a SQL newbie but I think my approach would be to first subset possible matches by using ST_Intersects (or whatever is appropriate for your geometries). Since they're already indexed, this should be really fast. Then look for exact matches within the candidates. At least that's how I'd approach it--I'm not good enough to quickly write an example.

Comment: You must not use `=`. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223342/what-does-it-mean-when-st-equals-returns-false-and-returns-true

Comment: @user30184 that behavior has changed with PostGIS 2.4.0 - it checks byte sequence equality now, while `~=` checks for *bounding box* equality.

Comment: @user30184 Yes, `=` is not the same as `st_equals`, but one of the comments in that post points out that `=` is improved.  I may be able to get away with the changed functionality...but I would still prefer st_equals http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2017/09/postgis-operators.html

Comment: @Jon - thanks for the suggestion.  I added to my post some detail that I didn't think to include earlier.  Basically, I expect that a subset using st_intersects would return nearly the entire dataset because the two tables are largely the same.  So I like the idea, but I suspect (though haven't tested) that I'd face a similar issue because I'd still have a similar number of records

Comment: The improved `=` acts like “A and B have exactly the same vertices in the same order and with the same starting points”. However, the OGC Simple Features model does not care about vertex order. This is false `select 'LINESTRING (0 0,1 1)'='LINESTRING (1 1,0 0)'` but this is true `select ST_Equals('LINESTRING (0 0,1 1)','LINESTRING (1 1,0 0)')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plain `=` implementation for the `GEOMETRY/GEOGRAPHY` types directly compare their encoded *byte sequences*, which naturally is *much* faster than determining *geometric* likeliness, *especially* for higher dimensional geometries like *LineString*s and - even more so - *Polygon*s.

The most idiomatic way to check for existence is an `EXISTS` anti-join:

```
SELECT
  p1.geom
FROM
  schema1.parcel AS p1
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      schema2.parcel AS p2
    WHERE
      p1.geom && p2.geom
      AND
      ST_Equals(p1.geom, p2.geom)
  )
;
```

`EXISTS` short-circuits out of execution once the first row is added to its virtual result set, meaning that you benefit greatly from any *early* hits - which coincidences with your assumption of only a small fraction being non-existent¹.

I added an explicit call to the `&&` *bounding box* overlap operator to coerce the planner into using an index lookup - I do not see the index being used with the actual `~=` *bounding box* **equality** operator, nor `ST_Equals` alone in most cases, but I still suggest to at least test `~=` on *Polygon*s!
From your linked question on the motherboard it seems PostgreSQL's planner also greatly confuses the worthiness of the index on the *Primary Key*.

That being said, this will still need to loop over all rows in `schema1.parcel` and potentially apply `ST_Equals` on one or more index hits in `schema2.parcel` - but that cost is a fixed given in an anti-join, no matter the expression.

---

¹ this is a tricky assumption, though: a negative index lookup should be much faster to resolve than an early hit with an `ST_Equals` check applied on potentially complex *Polygon*s - even more so when the index is looking for *bounding box* **overlap**. This, again, is the nature of an anti-join, so there is not much you can change about it.